# POST method is returning 400 error code with ReactNative

Tags: react-native, post, axios, http-status-code-400

I have found this question here before , but no of the solutions worked for me..
So in a react native app I have to post an image file and then display the predicted results
as following :

```
        "age": integer,
        "gender": string
```

The post method works well in postman :     [postman result json](https://i.stack.imgur.com/jlnDo.png)

but when in react native it returns     `**AxiosError: Request failed with status code 400**`     [error](https://i.stack.imgur.com/c5k45.png) Here is the code related to axios :

```
axios.interceptors.request.use(
  async config => {
    let request = config;
    request.headers = {
      'Content-Type': 'application/json',
      Accept: 'application/json',
    };
    request.url = configureUrl(config.url);
    return request;
  },
  error => error,
);

export const {height, width} = Dimensions.get('window');
export const configureUrl = url => {
  let authUrl = url;
  if (url && url[url.length - 1] === '/') {
    authUrl = url.substring(0, url.length - 1);
  }
  return authUrl;
};
export const fonts = {
  Bold: {fontFamily: 'Roboto-Bold'},
};
const options = {
  mediaType: 'photo',
  quality: 1,
  width: 200,
  height: 200,
  includeBase64: true,
};
const App = () => {
  //const [gender, setGender] = useState('');
  //const [age, setAge] = useState('');
  const [label, setLabel] = useState('');
  const isDarkMode = useColorScheme() === 'dark';
  const [image, setImage] = useState('');
  const backgroundStyle = {
    backgroundColor: isDarkMode ? Colors.darker : Colors.lighter,
  };
  const [result, setResult] = useState('');

  const getPredication = async params => {
    return new Promise((resolve, reject) => {
      var bodyFormData = new FormData();
      bodyFormData.append('file', params);
      let url = 'https://us-central1-potato-disease-382301.cloudfunctions.net/predict';
      //Config.URL;
      return axios
        .post(url, bodyFormData)
        .then(response => {
          resolve(response);
        });
});
  };
```

```
const manageCamera = async type => {
    try {
      if (!(await PermissionsService.hasCameraPermission())) {
        return [];
      } else {
        if (type === 'Camera') {
          openCamera();
        } else {
          openLibrary();
        }
      }
    } catch (err) {
      console.log(err);
    }
  };
const openCamera = async () => {
    launchCamera(options, response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const uri = response?.assets[0]?.uri;
        const path = Platform.OS !== 'ios' ? uri : 'file://' + uri;
        setResult(path, response);
      }
    });
  };
  const clearOutput = () => {
    setResult('');
    setImage('');
  };
  const getResult = async (path, response) => {
    setImage(path);
    setLabel('Predicting...');
    setResult('');
    const params = {
      uri: path,
      name: response.assets[0].fileName,
      type: response.assets[0].type,
    };
    const res = await getPredication(params);
    //if (res.data.gender) {
      setLabel(res.data.gender);
      setResult(res.data.age);
    //} else {
    //  setLabel('Unable to predict');
    //}
  };
  const openLibrary = async () => {
    launchImageLibrary(options, async response => {
      if (response.didCancel) {
        console.log('User cancelled image picker');
      } else if (response.error) {
        console.log('ImagePicker Error: ', response.error);
      } else if (response.customButton) {
        console.log('User tapped custom button: ', response.customButton);
      } else {
        const uri = response.assets[0].uri;
        const path = Platform.OS !== 'ios' ? uri : 'file://' + uri;
        getResult(path, response);
      }
    });
  };
```

Comment: It'll make your post a little easier to read if you just include the code in code blocks instead of using image files (embedding the error and postman images could also help)

Comment: @fordat Done for the code . And I already included the postman image link , It's my first post in stackoverflow and I need to get reputation of 10 to be able to display images ..